# What does "dainty" mean in this context?

Tags: translation, wasei-eigo

What does the "dainty" below "Liquor and Drink" mean/correlate to? This seems like 和製英語 of some kind but I can't figure out what it could be from or what sort of meaning or purpose it's intended for here. I tried googling around but it doesn't seem like this has been asked online, that or I can't figure out the right keywords to use for this; I've tried looking up the store in English and katakana, tried appending "dainty" in English and katakana, and a couple other things but haven't gotten much luck.

[image: A sign of the Japanese stores that says Belc, ベルク, 焼きたてパン, パン・コキール, LIQUOR & DAINTY, 酒, DRINK & DAINTY, クリーニング アニカ]

Comment: Look up dainty as a noun. You'll find it's not 和製英語 but just a word that has fallen out of use. It means "Something delicious to the taste" so someone probably looked up 珍味 or 美味しいもの and found that word. Unfortunately that means this is a question about English and not Japanese, so I didn't make an answer.

Comment: Oh. Oops, sorry. Didn't even consider it could have been obsolete English. Thank you though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it turns out this ended up being a question about English rather than Japanese.

Comment: No, it is definitely a question about Japanese, because the questioner may well be perfectly aware of the (non-obsolete) English adjective, but wants to know what the Japanese means, if anything.

Comment: @BrianChandler the user trying to close this question is the questioner themself.

Comment: @BrianChandler what Japanese is there to question the meaning of? Are you suggesting that we assume something like デインティー and answer that, even though it's not written?

Comment: @Leebo, one could argue that -- while this term originated as English -- the term as shown on this sign may represent a peculiarly Japanese usage.  So less 和[製]{●}英語, and perhaps more 和[用]{●}英語? Much like _"salaryman"_ was originally English, then fell out of use, and got popularized again in Japanese contexts.  As English, _"dainty"_ is still in use -- but much more commonly as an adjective, with a sense of _"something small, refined, fragile, perhaps even cute"_.  I don't think I've ever encountered this as a noun on a business sign in the English-speaking world, for instance.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi as interesting as the usage is, it still strikes me as off topic for the Japanese language SE, since they're not trying to use it as Japanese (to my eye). I imagine some people might feel differently though. If, for instance, someone in Japan used strange or archaic Korean or French, that too would feel off topic to me.

Comment: This is the first time I have ever seen this word. I haven’t seen it in katakana, either. It is definitely not part of the Japanese language in the way *salaryman* is.